# How to configure git to ignore file changes but still restore it?

Tags: git

I have a .h file that I generate with a script to assign macros to the git hash and branch name.  I want to store a template of this file with git, assigning the macros to an error message instead of hash/branch.  It cannot contain the hash and branch, because if you update the file with a hash, it will change the hash again.

I'd like the template to have the same name, so the project will build and display an error message if the script isn't run.  I'd like to store this template in an initial commit, and ignore subsequent changes, but still restore the file when checking out another branch/committing as to avoid incorrect hash and branch getting built into the program.

I am looking into

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <file.h>
```

and

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file.h>
```

but I think these have a couple flaws for my application

`--skip-worktree` doesn't let me checkout a different branch, saying that version.h will be overwritten.

`--assume-unchanged` doesn't restore the file when I checkout or even git restore.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why use the same name? Seems like the build should either fail if the .h file is missing, or build it using the template as a build step.

Comment: Can you elaborate on use the template as a build step?  It would be nice for the project to build without the script running.  Otherwise, it would be confusing for someone to look for the .h and not find it.  Adding a template with a different name would just add clutter to the project, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Why would it be any more confusing than not finding a `.o` file that needs to be generate from a `.c` file? Keep `foo.h.template` in the repository, and have your build tool generate `foo.h` from `foo.h.template` using your script if `foo.h` isn't found.

Comment: That is good idea.  How would I go about doing that?  Thanks!

Comment: That depends entirely on what build tool you are using, and this isn't the place to ask how to start using one. There are language-agnostic build tools like `make`, and there are build tools specific to particular languages. Look into the options most relevant to the language your are writing your project in.

Comment: Yeah, it might be possible with the tools I am using, but it is a lot more work to configure that than the git thing.  I am surprised that this is not addressed better in git.

Comment: Why should it be? Git's job is to monitor changes to tracked files. You are asking it to *not* to that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some build tool to generate `foo.h` from `foo.h.template` if it is missing. `foo.h.template` is the only one you commit to your repository. For example, a Makefile processed by `make` would include a target like

```
foo.h: foo.h.template
        yourScript foo.h.template

someFile: foo.h
        someOtherCommand
```

If you run `make someFile`, `make` will run `someOtherCommand` if `someFile` does not exist, or if `someFile` exists but is older than `foo.h`. If `foo.h` itself does not exist or is older than *its* dependency `foo.h.template`, then it will run `yourScript foo.h.template` first to bring `foo.h` up to date, *then* run `someOtherCommand` to bring `someFile` up to date.